# HCI Socket Options

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, hci

Defined in the Bluez bluetooth stack in hci.h is the following:

```
/* HCI Socket options */ 
#define HCI_DATA_DIR    1
#define HCI_FILTER      2
#define HCI_TIME_STAMP  3
```

I've only seen HCI_FILTER being used to set HCI event filters for the host. I have been unable to find any resources that explain what the other two options (HCI_DATA_DIR and HCI_TIME_STAMP) are used for and what is expected for option_value when calling setsockopt().

Is there any sort of documentation that goes over these details?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this?

Comment: I found documentation that goes over timestamping for network packets here: 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt
Since the host controller interface (HCI) is implemented through sockets using Bluez the documentation does apply.
Once upon a time I figured out what HCI_DATA_DIR but I was mainly focused on figuring out what was possible with timestamps.

Comment: HCI_DATA_DIR stands for data direction. If you look at the code here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/bluez/+/refs/heads/master/monitor/hcidump.c you will find an error code printout that implies that the option adds additional info to each bluetooth packet. Specifically, it lets you know whether the packet is incoming or outgoing.

Comment: Using socket.recv (python), I don't see any difference in the buffer returned between enable or disabling either. Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe I need [recvmsg](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvmsg) which returns `data, (cmsg_level, cmsg_type, cmsg_data), msg_flags, addr`?

Comment: strange, I get no values for cmsg_* but msg_flags= 0 if both disabled but msg_flags = 8 if either or both enabled

Comment: I used C for my implementation and had a for loop that went through all available control messages until it found the timestamp. I had to check and make sure the cmsg_level == SOL_HCI and cmsg_type == HCI_CMSG_TSTAMP. It worked for me but I needed nanosecond resolution, so I had to go a different route.